# Play Framework : REST url with a form parameter

Tags: playframework

Play!Framework allows you to write a form with an input name "message.id" and then write an action like so

```
public static void getMessage( Message message )
{
    ....
}
```

So the parameter message.id is translated to the model Message using "findById" on the value.

Play also allows you to write REST urls. 
For example 
    GET /message/{id}

but in this case the action signature is

```
public static void getMessage( long id )
{
    ....
}
```

In this case, I need to call Message.findById by myself.

I am trying to do a combination like so

```
GET /message/{message.id}    MessageController.getMessage
```

and the action to be

```
public static void getMessage( Message message ){ ... }
```

but I couldn't get it to work. 
How do I get it to work if I am using play 1.2.1?

I found a google group thread on this : [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/7JdAYZ2RShc)

Answer (score 0):

You can't *mix* the two, and it wouldn't have much sense. Play's [pojo object binding](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#anamepojoPOJOobjectbindinga) lets you write an action method with a Java object as a parameter, but the mechanism only works if you follow its conventions. If you want to pass a `Message` to `getMessage()` simply define the route as follows:

```
GET    /message/{message}    MessageController.getMessage
```

and you will be able to pick the right Message via a URL like `/message/message.id=123`